# CassandraCacheStoreFactory not load dataSourceBean

Tags: ignite

I started Ignite on the server with default configs. My application connects to the ignite server as a server/client and load the cache configuration and create the cache by uses CassandraCacheStoreFactory.

Zero deploy feature doesn't work for cache store. I should provide cache store configuration and implementation for each node in cluster ???

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

If you mean [peer class loading](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/zero-deployment#peer-class-loading), then yes, class for a cache store cannot be loaded from remote nodes. Peer class loading works only for objects, that have short bounded lifetime, like [compute tasks](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/compute-grid) or [data stream receivers](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/data-streamers#section-streamreceiver).

In case of a cache store, its class should be on a class path of every node in the cluster, that will participate in transactions, using the cache store. But the safest way is just to put it to the class path of every node in the cluster.

Specifying cache store configuration on every node is not mandatory. Only nodes, that create a cache or have it in a static config should have this configuration.